# Trouble: can you move any peg on your second pop after landing on double trouble?

Tags: trouble

My kids are having a debate about how Trouble should work. If you land on a Double Trouble, you are granted a second turn. Do you have to move the peg that is on the Double Trouble spot, or can you move any peg?

The instructions don't say, but I could see it either way:

- it's just another turn, so any peg could be moved
- you got the turn by virtue of the peg that landed there, so it's another turn for *that* peg, specifically

**Note:** this game doesn't seem to be tagged here, and I can't find a generic "board game" or similar tag. Someone with more rep should feel free to better categorize this.

Comment: I've not found a rules source that references taking extra turns.  I've found rules at https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Trouble,_Double.pdf but they don't refer to extra goes.  What I would suggest is checking your rules and seeing if 'turn' is defined anywhere and thats what an extra turn is.   Your second suggestion to me has a feel of someones house rule that they they were taught or a rule is being made up on the spot!   If an extra turn was for a specific peg then thats the sort of thing which should be explicitly stated in the rules. If its not then its probably not the rule

Comment: Interestingly, those instructions don't look like our board, and the [regular Trouble one](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Trouble.pdf) doesn't mention the double spot! I'll look at the rules more closely; good idea. We are talking a 9 and 7 year old, and the elder was making the calls, so it could very well be a "house rule." I just couldn't solve it for them and decided to bring it here :)

Comment: When I was that age who claimed in chess he could talk an 'extended move' which meant moving same piece twice.  When did the same I kept getting told it wasn't allowed!  I also sometimes find most rules issues with adults are caused by players being taught a game wrong and the error spreads.  Many a time I've found I've been playing a game wrong for years until someone points out the error or you notice it in the rules

Answer (score 2):

According to a review of Trouble, not Double Trouble, which is a different game, on boardgamegeek.com, the player takes another turn. Which pegs, if any, a player can move on a turn is dependent on the die roll. Players have turns; pegs do not. The extra turn belongs to the player, not the peg.

https://boardgamegeek.com/video/120000/trouble/trouble-review-warp-and-double-trouble-additions

Comment: Would you be able to add a link to the review for reference?